# Passing variables in Jade

Tags: pug

I'm trying to pass variables from the calling express application to a jade template and from there to a base template and some includes/mixins. I want to set a default value in case the parameter is not passed.

I'm looking for a good description of the variable scope throughout the entire call chain (template, base template, includes and mixins). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

While doing some testing to get a better understanding I tried very simple application does not return what I would have expected:

Calling application:

```
res.render('bla', {whatever: 'whatever!'});
```

bla.jade:

```
- var whatever = (whatever || 'no whatever')

html
  body
    h1=(whatever)
```

I would have expected to see 'whatever!' but the result is 'no whatever'. Removing the 'var' line yields 'whatever!' so the parameter does get passed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out why the test didn't work... the 'var' keyword defines a local variable which masks the passed parameter before the assignment is made. Removing the 'var' keyword does the trick.